# Bash variable is being modified by a function and loses its changes

Tags: bash

I was expecting this code to produce

```
A
A A
A A A A
A A A A A A A A
.....
```

But instead I get

```
A
A
A
A
...
```

Code :

```bash
fun() {

    var=$1

    echo $var #for debugging

    var=$var" "$var

    fun $var

}

fun "A"
```

Can you please explain me why and how to get the expected output ?

See above               .

Comment: Quote your variables to avoid wordsplitting: `fun "$var"`

Answer (score 1):

Reusing the most of your code as possible (need to add quotes properly):

```
fun() {
    var=$1
    echo "$var"                 # for debugging
    var="$var $var"             # look the quote style
    ((${#var} > 50)) && return  # avoid infinite recursion
    fun "$var"
}

fun "A"
```

Learn how to quote properly in shell, it's very important :

> "Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and *every* expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. Use `'single quotes'` for code or literal `$'s: 'Costs $5 US'`, `ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'`. See
> http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
> http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments
> http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words
> [when-is-double-quoting-necessary](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary)

### Output

```
A
A A
A A A A
A A A A A A A A
A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers seem to be addressing the infinite recursion but not why the output is not as expected.

The reason you only get `A` instead of `A A`, `A A A A`, etc, is simply that you call `fun $var` instead of `fun "$var"`.

Because, `$var` contains whitespace, if you do not quote it, it gets split (into `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, etc) instead of remaining as a single argument.

Comment: Technically, it is split on values in `$IFS` not whitespace. cf.[Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html), [Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting), etc

Comment: The default **is** whitespace. Nitpicking

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to store `$1` in a variable and need quotes around function argument.

This function should work for you:

```bash
fun() {
   [[ ${#1} -gt 20 ]] && return  # bail out when length is > 20
   echo "$1"                     # echo passed value
   fun "$1 $1"                   # call function recursively
}
```

**Test:**

```bash
fun "*"
*
* *
* * * *
* * * * * * * *

fun "A"
A
A A
A A A A
A A A A A A A A
```

---

If you want to increment one character in each row in output then use:

```bash
fun() {
   [[ ${#1} -gt 20 ]] && { unset var; return; } # bail out & unset var
   [[ -z $var ]] && var="$1"                    # set var first time
   echo "$1"                                    # echo passed value
   fun "$var $1"                                # recursive call 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yes I misinterpreted the requirement. Addressed it now.

Answer (score 0):

A simplified function definition:

```
$ fun() { echo "$1"; fun "$1 $1"; } 
     
$ fun "A" | head -6
A
A A
A A A A
A A A A A A A A
A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A
A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A
```

**NOTES:**

- the double quoting is *important* to insure the entire line of `A's` is treated as a single string
- the `head -6` is used here to keep from going into an infinite loop

One idea for limiting the recursion depth would be to keep track of a recursion level, either hardcoded in the function or possibly as an additional argument to the function call; one idea for implementing the latter:

```
$ fun() { echo "$1"; [[ "$2" -le 1 ]] && return; fun "$1 $1" $(($2-1)) ; }

$ fun "A" 6
A
A A
A A A A
A A A A A A A A
A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A
A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A
```

**NOTES:**

- again, double quoting all variable references is required, especially since we're passing the recursion limit as the 2nd argument (ie, we need to distinguish between the growing line of `A's` and the number in the 'last' position)
- OP can decide if additional logic should be added to verify the 2nd argument is in fact a) an integer and b) greater than 0; additional logic could use a default if the 2nd argument is not provided (eg, `${2:-4}` ==> default 1st call to using `4`)
- with some additional coding the recursion limit could be passed as the 1st  argument